# mod_rewrite loop issue with usernames

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, loops, redirect

I am using mod_rewrite to make profile page usernames as in mydomain.com/johndoe

The code below works just fine **until** I try going to a **directory** like www.mydomain.com/images, upon which I get thrown into an infinite loop to http://www.mydomain.com/images/?username=images

Current Code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Add WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect usernames
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you say the latter doesn't work, you mean if you try accessing a directory such as your above example, it still gets throw into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you have to decide wether it's an existing directory, or a fake uri which contains a username or other actions which gonna call some php-scripts or something.

The way with !-d is right, but there is also !-f for files.

Try something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```